# Kivy, Python 3.8 - Unable to get SoundLoader working properly

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, kivy, kivy-language

I'm making an app/game and the user is able to play a sound when pressing the sound button, and the same sound is played after the user finishes a level. The next level contains a new sound.

For some reason, my code doesn't act how I want it and the results aren't consistent: sometimes it works only once, sometimes it works twice or more. Sometimes the next level contains the new sound but most of the time it doesn't play anything.

It probably has something to do with the way I load/try to unload audio files because the code returns 'play' when printing out the audio state.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
import time

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

root_widget = Builder.load_file('app.kv')


class ExampleWidget(Widget):

    def play_sound(self):

        file = 'correct.wav'
        print('playing ', file)

        click_sound = SoundLoader.load(file)

        click_sound.play()

        time.sleep(2)
        print(click_sound.state)
        click_sound.stop()
        print(click_sound.state)

        #click_sound.unload()  #  Crashes the app
        click_sound = ''


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return ExampleWidget()


MyApp().run()
```

app.kv:

```
<ExampleWidget>:
    id: ew
    GridLayout:
        col: 2
        rows: 3
        size: root.size
        Button:
            text: 'play sound'
            size: self.size
            on_release: ew.play_sound()
```

I also tried to empty the click_sound variable by assigning it a None value, using 'del click_sound', tried emptying the variable at the start of the function, end or both and I also tried using the unload() function but that returns the following error:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

I'm also getting the following warning. I don't think it's a part of my problem but I'm adding it just in case:

```
[WARNING] [ffpyplayer  ] [wav @ 0x7fc738908e00] Discarding ID3 tags because more suitable tags were found.
```

Hopefully someone can help me out, I thank you in advance.

EDIT:
As ApuCoder said, the code works fine, just not on my macbook. Just tested it on a Windows pc and there were no problems. Does anybody know a way to fix this on Apple computers?

Comment: Your posted code ran as expected with valid audio file. However you could've used [`Clock`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#module-kivy.clock) instead of `time.sleep` to prevent gui irresponsiveness.

Comment: That's weird, I'll have to try running my code on another device. I'm using MacOS and there were some problems using kivy audio on Macs. I'm also going to use Clock, thank you.